# Convert environment variable to integer in Postma request's body

Tags: environment-variables, postman

I have the following Pre-request script in Postman that sets environment variables

```
var current_timestamp = Date.now();
var current_timestamp = current_timestamp ;
var past = current_timestamp - 134;
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("current_timestamp", Number(current_timestamp));
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("past", Number(past));
```

These variables are referred back in the body of the request:

```
{
    "timestamps": [ "{{current_timestamp}}", "{{past}}"] 
}
```

However, the variables are saved as strings, not as integer. I would like to have in the request body integer values. I tried using `Number` in the script as suggested in another answer but it does not change a thing.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the double quotes: `{{current_timestamp}}` instead of `"{{current_timestamp}}"`.

Comment: Also, `postman.setEnvironmentVariable()` is the older syntax - You should think about changing this too `pm.environment.set()`. There is other functions available under that `pm.environment` method too which are not part of the older syntax.